# Textbooks with examples of continuous functionals

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, calculus-of-variations, function-spaces

I am an undergraduate student in Mathematics and am interested in learning Calculus of Variations on my own, so I asked an older semester student if I could borrow his class notebook. Reviewing the first notes, I found a brief introduction to Functional Analysis, which includes the definition of functional and continuity of a functional. Later I saw the following example

Let $f\in C([a,b],\mathbb{R})$ and $J:C([a,b],\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ the functional $J[x]=\int_a^b(f(t)+x^2(t))dt$.

In this example, he proved that this functional is continuous, using a trick to determine what is the proper delta for each given epsilon. I asked him what book his class was based on but he told me that his teacher never mentioned what book it was based on. I would like to review books in which this specific type of example comes, in which a functional is proposed that goes from a function space like $C([a,b],\mathbb{R})$  to real numbers and we are asked whether or not it is continuous, since that way I could become familiar with the reasoning behind the tricks to get the proper delta. Does anyone know of any books where this specific example comes? Or similar examples? Thanks in advance

Comment: This is an example of a linear functional on a Banach space. Continuity here is equivalent to boundedness. No need for a direct epsilon/delta proof.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator

Comment: Hi, @Manuel. The is a classical book on Functional Analysis by Brezis. It may be a little bit complicated now for you to follow up, but look for some "introduction" book on this topic and you may find those definitions and examples. The thing to deal with linear maps between normed vector spaces that have infinite dimension and understand continuity in this context.

Comment: @JoshuaTilley Boundedness had not yet been introduced. I think his professor asked them to do it with an epsilon delta proof for didactic reasons. Later in his notes he demonstrates again the continuity of this same functional with the boundedness argument that you mention. I asked this question because i want to see more examples like this that are treated in a more rudimentary way, so that i can better understand the definition of continuity and then follow with the definition of boundedness and use the basic results related to it. Thank you

Comment: @YgorArthur thank you! I think I will look up for those kind of books first and then I will go for the book you mention